# ggplot : make a facet-wrap for specific value of two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a data frame (`DF`) that is structured like this :

```
RMS | measure | parameter | tirage | case | nombre
```

Here is the link to [my data frame](http://www.wikiupload.com/EVEMX5GHGVTE7HZ).
I want to plot `RMS` as my `y` Vs. `nombre`as my `x` for different `measure` but for a specific value of `parameter` as well as a specific value of `case`. I have already tried this :

```
ggplot(data = DF, aes(factor(nombre), RMS, case = 2, parameter = 1)) +
geom_boxplot() +  
facet_wrap( ~ measure, scales = "fixed", ncol = 1)
```

But it does not work. It still plots all data corresponding to all values of `case` and all values of `measure`. I searched a bit and I saw that if it was just one variable (either `case` or `measure`), I could simply use `group = specific value`. But since we have two variables, I don’t know how I should specify this. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include example data so we can reproduce your problem. You can use `dput` and paste your data into the question, or, better yet, rework your example to work with a builtin dataset like `mtcars` or `iris`

Comment: Does this work: `ggplot(DT, aes(factor(nombre), RMS)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~ measure + case + parameter)`?

Comment: Maybe this: `subset(DF, case == 2 & parameter == 1)`?

Comment: `library(dplyr); ggplot(data = DF %>% filter(case == 2, parameter == 1),  aes(factor(nombre), RMS) ....`

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will give you a badge and some useful knowledge. You should illustrate your specific problem in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). I took a quick look at your questions and none of them had a reproducible example. You can read [how to make a reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to learn what type of info your question should include. Cheers.

Comment: @Reyhaneh you did not. If you've actually bothered to scan through those links, you would've gotten the badge and known that a link to data is not fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = DF %>% filter(case == 2, parameter == 1), 
       aes(factor(nombre), RMS)) +
geom_boxplot() +  
facet_wrap( ~ measure, scales = "fixed", ncol = 1)
```